# Xdebug with PHPStorm 8 -- opens WRONG file at non-existing breakpoint

Tags: debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I am having trouble using Xdebug with PHPStorm. I have searched Google, etc.

I have Xdebug setup on a remote host with my local files mirroring the remote host. I am using the Xdebug Chrome extension.

When I run the debugging through PHPStorm, it OPENS a file and shows a blue-highlighted breakpoint that does NOT exist at that file. It will stay there until I hit "resume" multiple times until I get to the file I actually want to debug. VERY annoying because then the session on Chrome timesout, so I can't debug.

I do not see any code that says `xdebug_break();` and I never added a breakpoint to that file. In other words, there are no red markings at the left of the line numbers.

What is going on and how do I fix this? Has anyone else come across this problem?

I have tried skipping and ignoring the file ... still does not work! Yes, I have also viewed breakpoints through a separate window and it does not show the breakpoint that apparently exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the configuration on PHPStorm stop at first line property and disable it

[image]

After that  go to Run >>  Break at first line in PHP scripts

Try turning it ON and OFF few times. Sometimes it is get stuck in between: showing OFF but in reality it is ON.

This is a well known issue Read: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17389

Comment: Sorry this is a dummy question. did you restart PHPStorm after you did that?, sorry it is a really silly question but sometimes, it saves the day

Comment: Those are already unselected... I had to go to Run -> Break at first line in PHP Script.

Comment: Yes... 

I've uninstalled multiple times too. Even resynced file directory. Had sysadmin look in config files.

NOBODY could figure it out.

Comment: and it does it for only one project or for all of them? it always breaks at the same line?

Comment: NOPE! Just my Mac on my own dev server. Everyone else's worked.

Comment: I don't even know if your answer was correct ... those two things were unselected, but it did make me go to "Run -> Break at first line in PHP Script" and now it's working...so I'm happy. LOL.

Comment: I am going to add that to my answer so it make some "sense"

Comment: The WI-17389 ticket is already resolved -- fix will be available in **v9**. If you wish -- you may try EAP build (sort of "alpha" version) even right now -- it's free (comes with own 30-days license) and can be run alongside to v8 -- http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2015/02/phpstorm-9-early-access-program-started/

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with my PHPStorm/xdebug config.  It turned out I had the path mappings wrong when I mapped the root of the local file directory to the Absolute path on the server - Settings->Languages and Frameworks -> PHP -> Servers.

I fixed the mapping and the system is behaving predictably once again.